# ggplot2 + stat_contour variable binwidth

Tags: r, ggplot2

What I'm trying to do is to have a variable binwidth in a ggplot2 contour plot, that is the distance between the different "equi-level lines".

Here is a minimal working example from the documentation, **with a constant binwidth**:

```
# Generate data
library(reshape2) # for melt
volcano3d <- melt(volcano)
names(volcano3d) <- c("x", "y", "z")

# Basic plot
v <- ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y, z = z))
v + stat_contour(aes(colour=..level..), binwidth = 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `breaks` argument, for example:

```
v <- ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y, z = z))
v + stat_contour(aes(colour= ..level..), breaks = c(100, 101, 102, 105, 110, 150, 175))
```

[image]

Comment: In this case it is seemingly undocumented, but as all the binning in `ggplot` works the same (afaik) you can find this in the documentation for `stat_bin`. Not very obvious.